# Error after update

Tags: appcelerator-studio

After I made update Appcelerator Studio to version 4.5.0 I got this error:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ITitaniumUserManager.getSignedInUser()Lcom/appcelerator/titanium/core/user/ITitaniumUser;
```

I'm signed in.

Can anybody help?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: What does the error log show?  Copy and paste it in your question

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its the same error but after I updated to 4.5.0 I had a login error.  Just try closing down and re-opening appcelerator again and logging back in.